# Ubuntu 18.10 / Gnome: Text and UI elements get blurry in some windows after a while -- how do I debug and fix this?

Tags: gnome, graphics, wayland

Since a few days (after updating Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10) the text and UI elements get blurry in some windows after a while. The effect is isolated to single windows, not the whole screen. I have a Dell XPS i7-7560, Kaby Lake GT3e graphics, and a Dell P2415Q screen. I am running Gnome on Wayland.

How do I debug and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove MS Core font installer using this command:
sudo apt remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Had the same issue since last week right after i installed it. Now, 30 seconds before writing this message, I removed it and its all good.

Comment: I don't see how MS Core Font installer would be linked to the issue I am observing. Can you provide some insight?

Comment: I am no geek. I just went through the list of latest installation on my ubuntu and noticed that it all started right after i installed ms core font installer.. so i removed it and the issue was resolved.

Comment: I did have MS Core Font Installer, so I removed it from my system. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: I'd like to report this as a bug in Ubuntu on launchpad. However, filing a bug for Ubuntu/launchpad seems to assume that I know the package that causes the bug. How can I report this bug without knowing the responsible package?

Comment: The issue seemed to be better for a while on my machine. However, after installing Ubuntu 19.10 (fresh install, not upgraded), it got worse than ever. The blurry windows seem to happen after waking up the computer from sleep mode. Windows that are newly opened do not have the problem. I am also seeing the problem on a new HP laptop with a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10, so the problem is not isolated to a specific machine.